# Will a good Java compiler omit a call to `String.format` with no format specifiers?

Tags: java, string, optimization, string.format

For example, if you have a line of code like this:

```
String vacuouslyFormatted = String.format("Number of items: 100");
```

Will the call to `String.format` most likely be omitted by the compiler since it does not affect the object referenced by `vacuouslyFormatted` in any way?

Comment: Not likely. The JIT compiler might optimize away some of the overhead.

Comment: Wouldn't it just throw a NullPointer Exception if you omit the format?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I think the OP meant no format _arguments_, not no format string.

Comment: Code like that is arguably faulty (i.e. needs fixing in the source code) rather than just non-optimal.  Finding stuff like that is best done using a static analysis tool; e.g. FindBugs, SpotBugs, PMD and the like.  (Though I don't know if the above is fault is within the capabilities of said tools.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; java isn't that kind of ecosystem.

All optimization is done by the runtime. The compiler (which turns `.java` files into `.class` files) *must follow the spec precisely*, and the spec (unlike, say, C), gives pretty much zero leeway or flexibility to the compiler. This source file must be turned into that sack of bytes. To the byte. Precisely. Or it's not a java compiler.

If you write `String.format` in the code, that has to be in the class file. After all, what if in some future edition of the `String` class that you end up running that code with, the `String.format("justAString")` call would produce something else? `javac` shouldn't make a decision that the spec of `String.format` cannot change like this.

What will happen in JDK21 (or 22, I'm not quite sure which version will get it), is compiler-supported string format directives. It looks like passing a string as it's a method:

```java
String name = "Jane";
int age = 8;
String formatted = STR."My name is \{name}, and I am \{age} years old";
assert "My name is Jane, and I am 8 years old".equals(formatted);
```

A runtime advantage here is that the **compiler** lops that format template string up into 3 substrings and 2 substitutions (`"My name is"`, `", and I am "`, and `" years old"`) and passes all that to `STR` (which you'd have to `import`). This means `STR` no longer has to, at runtime, go through the string and find `%`.

In contrast to `String.format("My name is %s, and I am %d years old", name, age);` where the code of `format` has to loop through the string and find percentage symbols.

Even in your case (`String.format("A string with no percent symbols and no arguments")`) it still has to look through for percentages. With the string templating feature it wouldn't have to do that.

The key point is that **The java language spec** would spell out that this is an option (in fact, it would spell out that a compiler **must** do it this way, if it deviates it would be just as wrong as a JDK20 compiler that compiles `String.format("abc")` as just `"abc"`).

NB: Standard 'future java' disclaimer: The OpenJDK team's discussions and feature implementations *leave syntax to the very last moment*, and are not at all interested in syntax discussions. It's not about what it looks like, it's about what it does. So if you like the idea but you find `STR."Hello"` looks weird, then [A] you may need to understand the full context of it all: Java doesn't break backwards compatibility; loads of proposals on how things should look are not possible because it's already valid java and therefore the meaning of it cannot just be changed without an extremely good reason to do so, and [B] that's not the interesting part, they probably don't currently care about syntax too much). I included what it currently looks like just as an aid to show what it does.

Comment: I don’t think that it would be illegal to incorporate the contract of the standard API into compiler decisions. After all, that’s what happens when the compiler decides that, e.g. calling `Integer.valueOf(int)` is sufficient to implement auto-boxing an `int` value to an `Integer` object; the API contract is compatible. However, calling `String.format(…)` with no placeholder nor arguments is a rare corner case and the compiler developers do not spend resources on optimizing rare corner cases. The overhead is way higher btw., as the `Formater` has to capture locale data before starting its work.

Comment: Btw. when you use good old concatenation and recent `javac`, the expression `"My name is " + name + ", and I am " + age + " years old"` will get compiled to a string with placeholders, however, the work of scanning them at runtime is done only once at the first execution, instead of every evaluation. This is considered as the most efficient solution, so uses of the standard string template processor (`STR."My name is \{name}, and I am \{age} years old"`) get compiled to the same code, as an optimization (demonstrating that compiling code literally is not needed when the contract is known).

Comment: The OpenJDK team has to date stuck to various unwritten rules: [1] Any runtime types mentioned in the Java Lang Spec exist in `java.lang`. This is why `java.lang.Iterable` exists which is bizarre, given that it's related to `java.util.Iterator`, split packages. String _is_ in `java.lang`, so, we crossed that hurdle. Nevertheless, [2] Hardcoding the impl of String `hashCode()` into its spec (by documenting how it works in the javadoc) has caused some hard-learned lessons ('mental trauma', if you like hyperbole) at the OpenJDK team. They.. don't do that anymore. This hurdle isn't crossed here.

Comment: More generally the number of hardcoded __implementations__ in the spec is virtually zero. The JDK doesn't encode explicit behaviour of implementations in the JLS, period. It'd be crazy if `String.format` is the very first time OpenJDK starts doing that.

Comment: `Integer.valueOf`'s implementation, as an example, isn't hardcoded in the JLS, and nowhere does the JLS state that Integer should cache -128 to +127 (even though it does). Yes, "use `Integer.valueOf` to implement auto-boxing, which is a JLS concept", is 'hardcoded' in the JLS. But not __how__ `Integer.valueOf` should do that job.

Comment: “nowhere does the JLS state that Integer should cache -128 to +127”—Well, except for [§5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7): “*If the value p being boxed is the result of evaluating a constant expression (§15.29) of type boolean, byte, char, short, int, or long, and the result is […] or an integer in the range -128 to 127 inclusive, then let a and b be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that a == b.*”, so for constant expressions, it relies on the fact that `Integer.valueOf` has compatible guarantees.

Comment: “it relies” means “the compiler relies”. Further note, I already mentioned that `STR."string with \{variable}"` is compiled into code that does not call into the processor in `STR` but get replaced with the same code as ordinary string concatenation instead, in other words, the compiler *does* utilize the knowledge about the contract, to replace the code with a different equivalent. By the way, the language specification also mentions `java.io.Serializable`, disproving the claim “*Any runtime types mentioned in the Java Lang Spec exist in java.lang*”

Comment: Huh, the JLS dives into the -128 to +127 caching thing? Well, TIL - that's.. a somewhat odd choice especially in light of the String.hashCode debacle. Thanks for digging that one up from the JLS!

Comment: It exists since Java 5 when autoboxing was introduced. And I always considered both, the JLS guaranty and the `valueOf` guaranty questionable, as caching is not always the most efficient option. It gets even worse when you look at [what difficulties they had to express their intention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59637974/2711488). But well, when we are at it, why does such guaranty exists for `String` constants, to name the older predecessor. We’re still discouraged from comparing strings using `==`, so why do we have a guaranty that it *sometimes* works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255177/discussion-between-holger-and-rzwitserloot).